Peculiar case of RSA
I am dealing with a case as follows:
P = 73, Q = 97.
N = 7081, phi(N) = 6912.
e = 7.
Now, to find decryption exponent 'd' we have to satisfy: (e * d) mod phi(N) = 1 - (i).
Aliter: d = e^(-1) mod phi(N) - (ii)

d = 7^(-1) mod 6912
d = 3,456

However, if we use the earlier identity:

(e * d) mod phi(N) = 1
Then it results to (7 * 3456) mod 6912 = 3456 ≠ 1

Now in this instance how can we re-concile the fact that the decryption exponent calculated as 3456 fails to satisfy (i)?


d = 7^(-1) mod 6912
d = 3,456

This value for $d$ is incorrect; the correct value is $d = 1975$.  We have $7 \times 1975 = 13825 = 1 \pmod {6912}$
I note that $3456 \bmod 72 = 0$ (and $72$ is one of the factors of $6912$, and so that cannot possibly be the decryption exponent.  The fact that decryption exponents are always odd is even a broader clue that it cannot be correct.
BTW: while having $d, e$ satisfy the relation $d \cdot e = 1 \pmod{\phi(n)}$ is sufficient, it is not necessary.  Instead, the sufficient and necessary condition for 2 factor RSA is the relation $d \cdot e = 1 \pmod{\text{lcm}(p-1, q-1)}$.  This can yield a smaller value for $d$; in this case, using this gives us the value $d = 247$, which also works as an RSA decryption exponent.

Thank you, you're right.
